# How to get the more repeated combination of list elements from a python list

Tags: python, list

I have few lists of names as below;

```
[['mallesham','yamulla'],['mallesham','yamulla'],['yamulla','mallesham']]
```

Here mallesham yamulla and mallesham yamulla person name is counted as two times hence the output should be ['mallesham','yamulla']

Second example:

```
[['Joe','Doe'],['Doe','Joe'],['Doe','Joe'],['Joe','Doe'],['Doe','Joe']]
```

Here Doe Joe counted as 3 times where as Joe Doe as 2 times, hence the output will be ['Doe','Joe']

In a 3rd case: what if all names have got equal number of counts as below

```
[['Joe','Doe'],['Doe','Joe'],['Doe','Joe'],['Joe','Doe']]
```

It should return any one of name such as Joe Doe.

Comment: OK, what is the *specific* problem you encountered while coding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
from collections import Counter
l = [['Joe','Doe'],['Doe','Joe'],['Doe','Joe'],['Joe','Doe'],['Doe','Joe']]
c = Counter([tuple(x) for x in l]).most_common(1)[0][0]
c
# ('Doe', 'Joe')
```